# I am trying to do a simulation using rnorm with 2 means and a standard deviation. But my responses differ wildly even with high n

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics

Say numPred is 10,000, meanDem is 44.06, the meanGOP is 46.34, and standard deviation is 3.5 for both.

```
AlabamaPred <- function(numPred, meanDem, meanGOP, StandardError) {
  x<-0
  Dem <- rnorm(numPred, mean = meanDem, sd=StandardError)
  GOP <- rnorm(numPred, mean = meanGOP, sd=StandardError)
  for(i in Dem){
    if (isTRUE(Dem[i] > GOP[i]))
    { 
      x = x+1 
      }
    else x
    x = x
  }
  return(x)
}
```

I got the Democrat winning 4,830 the first time, and the Democrat winning 2,324 the second time.

Why is there so much variance, even with the same variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `else x`, you are returning the value of x once `GOP[i]>=Dem[i]`, which means the counting stops. Thats why you have such a huge variation.

We can simplify the function like this:

```
AlabamaPred <- function(numPred, meanDem, meanGOP, StandardError) {
  Dem <- rnorm(numPred, mean = meanDem, sd=StandardError)
  GOP <- rnorm(numPred, mean = meanGOP, sd=StandardError)
  sum(Dem>GOP)
}
```

And now if we do it like 1000x, we can see the variation:

```
rep1000 = replicate(1000,AlabamaPred(10000,44.06,46.34,3.5))
hist(rep1000,br=50)
```

[image]